# Adsense hourly report

Tags: google-adsense, reporting

Can anyone tell me how I can see an hourly report of clicks/revenue/etc in Adsense?
The shortest time range I see is "Day", but it would be very important to see when people clicks on ads.

I didn't find any answer about this, maybe I'm missing something.
Thanks,
Mate

Answer (score 1):

Google AdSense doesn't currently offer hourly reports.  The most granular they have is "day."

You can submit Feedback to Google from your AdSense account saying that you would like this feature.   However, Google doesn't typically respond to feedback or act quickly to implement feature requests.